# How can I find max value for a text as unique identifier in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

This is basically for an auction setup in Google spreadsheet.
Say there are 26 bidders A to Z and each bid 5 times with different values. I need to find the max value bid by each of them and display next to it.

I'm using the below function to get the unique name list.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$200,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$200),0,0),0))
```

How do I proceed next by searching for all the values corresponding to a unique name and display next to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is sorting the spreadsheet by bid an option? For unique names in D, all names in A, and all bids in B, with A:B sorted descending by bid, do something like: `=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Excel's array functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) are very powerful tools, which come in handy with your question too. I assume column A has the bidders, B had the bids and D has the unique names.

Then in E1, put: `=MAX(IF(A:A=D1;B:B))` then press <kbd>CTRL></kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, which is the way to let Excel know you entered an *array function* instead of a normal function.

On a final note: array functions can not be copy-pasted down (I don'n know why), so you need to drag them down with the mouse (that works as you may expect).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It has a Group By command that can calculate the Max value for each bidder.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/group-rows-in-a-table-HA103993875.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993930